# Куда пропала буква Д в аббревиатуре ВИЧ?

Tags: аббревиатуры

Во-первых, интересует, как пишется аббевиатура "ВИЧ": строчными или прописными буквами? А во-вторых, не скрою, этот вопрос пришел в голову не мне, но тоже заинтересовал. Сокращение СПИД - это "синдром приобретенного иммунодефицита", а ВИЧ - "вирус иммунодефицита человека". Но, если в аббревиатуре "СПИД" "иммунодефицит" сократили двумя буквами: ИД, то в ВИЧ почему-то одной.
Так вот, куда пропала буква Д из аббревиатуры ВИЧ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее надо думать, зачем Д добавили к "СПИД". По общим подходам, оно там не теребкется.
Видимо, занесло от английского AIDS.  
Обе аббревиатуры - точные соответвия английским (своего рода "кальки"):
Human immunodeficiency virus infection / acquired immunodeficiency syndrome (HIV/AIDS).

При этом в обих языках очевидно влияние удобства произношения на выбор формы.

Answer (score 0):

Аббревиатура пишется прописными буквами (я встречал написание "ВИЧ-инфекция"). Что касается буквы Д, то такое происходит :)

Answer (score 0):

Д опущено, т.к. иначе было бы сложно читать эту аббревиатуру как слово.